# c function call error

Tags: c, function, loops

I was testing with c language today and I made two small c files

main.c

```
#include<conio.h>
void testing();
int main()
{
    testing();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

testing.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void testing()
{
    char ch;
    printf("Hello Testing\n");
    do{
        printf("Enter Character : ");
        ch=getchar();
        printf("You Entered : %c\n",ch);
        testing();
        }while(ch!='N');
}
```

The problem I am facing is it read one character from user and then it loop twice and I don't know why

```
output
Hello Testing
Enter Character : k //(i entered k)
You Entered : k

Hello Testing// why this is displayed twice??
Enter Character : You Entered :// i don't press any key and it moves to next iteration

Hello Testing
Enter Character : // here i can enter character again and it happens again twice
```

I have complied it on Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `getchar()` leaves a newline character in the input buffer. You can use another getchar() to eat the newline.

```
ch=getchar();
getchar();
```

Or use scanf to eat leading whitespaces:

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

This way all the previous `\n` will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

After printing the character, you re-call `testing()`. Which makes you loop on testing. Remove this line and you will be ok.

What you did not intentionally is [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29). This is a passionating aspect of computer programming, but not what you intended to do.

One more thing, think to read a second time to consume the newline left in the input buffer when you pressed enter to validate your input.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem might result from the fact that you call testing() function recursively in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is displayed twice because you have recursion in there, what is this function supposed to do that you have infinite recursion?